# Is it possible to report back the route name used when calling a Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to report back the route name used when calling a Web API?

I want to do some diagnostics in a "foo" project to see what route is called based on how/what I call. Is there a way for the action/api to see what route is used to reach it? Some sort of "route reflection"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Request.GetRouteData()` to get the route details for an action.

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Index()
    {
        var route = Request.GetRouteData();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```